# Does Django have an equivalent of Rails's “rails db:seed”?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

One thing I like about Rails projects is that you can create test content and place them in `seeds.rb` and seed them into the database by running `rake db:seed` instead of having to feed them one by one directly.

Is there something similar for Python/Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [migrations or fixtures may be what you are looking for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/).

Migrations would be Python code that can add data or manipulate the database schema.  Fixtures would be JSON formatted data that can be used as an initial data seed by using `python manage.py loaddata $FIXTURE`.

Comment: That has worked. Is there a way to now move data from the database to a fixture?

Comment: That would be [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata).  `python manage.py dumpdata` and has optional options to specify application, table, excludes, and other useful functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend looking at Factory Boy for test data creation. One could create records in series of loops to population any number of tables and build sensible relationships between records.